# images in not loading in webview Android

Tags: android, html, webview, base64, src

I have a issue in loading images in the webview. the normal images in the **src tags** are loading perfectly .but there is an custum image tag.

```
 <img class=\"lazy lazy-hidden aligncenter size-full wp-image-40307\" src=\"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=\" data-lazy-type=\"image\" data-lazy-src=\"http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg\" alt=\"yoyo\" width=\"600\" height=\"400\" title=\"Title\" />
```

i am loding the data in the webview like below

```
    news_deatilsWv
        .loadDataWithBaseURL(null, dataString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null)
```

**dataString** contain the the entire html data which i displayed, only this custom image portion is not loading.i search the web and found it is related t the base 64  encoding but cant find how to fix this. can any one suggest an idea or solution to fix this problem.